# java.lang.classcast exception error in android splashscreen

Tags: android

I have a splashscreen where i am geting error........

My class is :

```
package com.example.aajakobazzar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Splash extends Activity {
private Thread SplashThread;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    final ImageView splashImageView =   
            (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.SplashImageView);  
     splashImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splash);  
     final AnimationDrawable frameAnimation =   
                  (AnimationDrawable)splashImageView.getBackground();   
     splashImageView.post(new Runnable(){  
            @Override  
            public void run() {  
                frameAnimation.start();                  
            }              
        });  

    final Splash splashscreen = this;     

    // The thread to wait for splash screen events  
    SplashThread =  new Thread(){  
        @Override  
        public void run(){  
            try {  
                synchronized(this){  
                    // Wait given period of time or exit on touch  
                    wait(5000);  
                }  
            }  
            catch(InterruptedException ex){                      
            }  

            finish();  

            // Run next activity  
            Intent intent = new Intent();  
            intent.setClass(splashscreen, MainMenu.class);  
            startActivity(intent);  
            stop();                      
        }  
    };  

    SplashThread.start();          
}  


@Override  
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt)  
{  
    if(evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)  
    {  
        synchronized(SplashThread){  
            SplashThread.notifyAll();  
        }  
    }  
    return true;  
}
```

}

i got error..

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to startactivity
ComponentInfo{com.example.aajakobazzar/com.example.aajakobazzar.Splash}:
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
```

what can i do?????

Comment: clear from exception use (AnimationDrawable)splashImageView.getDrawable();

Comment: can yu elaborate.....

Comment: I am not using frames to create animaton..but i have only one image in drawable

Comment: @mehhancy So have you set background for imageview in xml file?? Check it

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
final AnimationDrawable frameAnimation =   
              (AnimationDrawable)splashImageView.getBackground();
```

to

```
final AnimationDrawable frameAnimation =   
              (AnimationDrawable)splashImageView.getDrawable();
```

Also Change:

```
splashImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splash);
```

to

```
splashImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.splash);
```

Answer (score 0):

As your R.drawable.splash is just an image and not any xml for animation, you need to make the object of BitmapDrawable instead of AnimationDrawable.
That is the actual reason for your error i guess.

try

```
  `final ImageView splashImageView =   (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.SplashImageView);
     splashImageView.setImageBitmap(null); 
     splashImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.splash);  
     final AnimationDrawable frameAnimation =             (AnimationDrawable)splashImageView.getDrawable();   
     splashImageView.post(new Runnable(){  
            @Override  
            public void run() {  
                frameAnimation.start();                  
            }              
        });  `
```

Comment: sorry for silly question but still want to confirm that, the drawable which you are using (splash) is actually an image or your xml for frameanimation ?

Comment: its just a image file..m not using frameanimation i.e. its nt a xml file

Comment: then what is the meaning of calling `frameAnimation.start();`?

Comment: @mehhancy did u find any solution to your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

```
final AnimationDrawable frameAnimation =   
                  (AnimationDrawable)splashImageView.getBackground();
```

Your problem is there, you are casting a `BitmapDrawable` to a `AnimationDrawable`. That causes a ClassCastException.

You should declare frameAnimation as a BitmapDrawable

Comment: after changing AnimationDrawable to BitmapDrawable still i m geting error

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable

Comment: @mehhancy have you set background for imageview in xml file?? Check it

Comment: What should i put in that??    

android:background="@drawable/"

Comment: Is your drawable (R.drawable.splash) a XML with an animation?, or your drawable is a simple image?

Comment: R.drawable.splash is a image file

Comment: OK, you cannot cast it to a AnimationDrawable directly, it will not animate calling frameAnimation.start() because it's just a bitmap. If you want to animate that image, you should create your own animations and call startAnimation method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#startAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)